# How to move strings contained in results of `nettop` using text editor?

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, zsh

using `sed`, `awk`, `ed`, etc... how to save an output string into a variable and print in a different position?

example output of `nettop`:

```bash
 iMac191 ~  nettop -l1 -n -J interface,state -p "$(/usr/bin/pgrep example.app)"                                 
                                                                                                      interface         state
example.77513
   tcp4 10.xxx.xxx.xxx:53410<->23.xxx.xxx.xxx:32146                                                         utun6       SynSent
   tcp4 10.xxx.xxx.xxx:36496<->185.xxx.xxx.xxx:50734                                                        utun6       SynSent
```

The first row's column 1 is "interface" and the second row's column 1 is "example.77513", so `column -t` command doesn't work. I need to move the 2nd row 1st column to 1st row 1st column, or vice versa, before using `column -t` to remove white space and keep header row

I would like the output to look something like this:

```bash
example.77513                                         interface      state
tcp4 10.xxx.xxx.xxx:53410<->23.xxx.xxx.xxx:32146      utun6          SynSent
tcp4 10.xxx.xxx.xxx:36496<->185.xxx.xxx.xxx:50734     utun6          SynSent
```

I plugged some questions into search and could only find [one example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136427/use-sed-or-awk-to-move-string-to-new-column-and-row) which I failed to repurpose for this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The header only has three columns, the table itself has four, so a dummy header is required to get the table formatting done correctly.

```bash
nettop -l1 -n -J interface,state -p "$(/usr/bin/pgrep example.app)" \
    | awk 'NR == 2 { gsub(/ /, "_");
                     print substr($0, 1, index($0, ".")+6),".","interface","state";
                     next
                   }
           NR > 2  { print $0 }' \
    | column -t
```

This just ignores the first line (it's always the same anyway) and creates the header out of line two, including `.` as a dummy header.

If you want to have the output as described in the question, you can use

```bash
nettop -l1 -n -J interface,state -p "$(/usr/bin/pgrep example.app)" \
    | awk 'NR == 2 { gsub(/ /, "_"); 
                     printf "%s\tinterface\tstate\n",substr($0, 1, index($0, ".")+6);
                     next
                   }
           NR > 2  { printf "%s %s\t%s\t%s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4 }' \
    | column -s $'\t' -t
```

`$'\t'` expands to a single-quoted tab character.

Comment: I didn't get proper results using either one verbatim. I did when combining elements from the first and second examples. Thank you for your effort! If you want me to edit your post to include what worked I can do that.

Comment: @John By all means, yes, I'm curious how it works different on your end.

Comment: @John Ah right, if the process name has whitespace in it, `column` gets confused

Comment: @John Updated with versions which replace whitespace in the process name by underscores.

Comment: These work as well, but the original is far less complicated. having a working example is really helpful for researching why things do what they do. I have never seen this before: `NR == 1 { next }`. if you could keep the various methods that work intact that would help understanding `awk`

Comment: @John `NR == 1 { next }` skips the first line, but it is not really needed here. `awk` scripts basically consist of patterns and actions, the input is read line by line and evaluated against each pattern. For each matching pattern, the actions are executed. Using your favorite search engine to search for "getting started with awk" should give you a lot of training material.

Comment: I have an O'Reilly book "sed & awk" that is ~400 pages long. I could flip through that, but without using those tools every day... difficult to retain the info. Looking at `next` in the book they mention `getline`. Unfortunately, I only seem to have the man page for `getline` and not the function on my system.

Comment: @John Check out `man awk`,  `getline` is described there (and also on page 265ff in the O'Reilly book). But in the code above, `getline` is irrelevant, `awk` reads each input line anyway and checks it against the pattern. `NR == 1 { next }` was there to skip the first line, but then I realized I could change the pattern so the first line just gets ignored.